# Призрачный CSS..

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Уже 2 день мучаюсь над такой проблемой:
У меня есть кусок шаблонизатора, на котором я делаю сайт, но не суть. В шаблонизаторе нету никакого кэширования и тп.. Я скачал SBAdmin2 шаблон и поставил, впихнув все куда нужно, настроив пути. Тема лежит по пути: xampp/nullsite/templates/SBAdmin2. Там есть папочка assets, где и лежит весь css, less, js и шрифты.

Когда я меняю что-либо в файлах css - оно не меняется на сайте. Но если я переиминую файл с css, и в head'е тоже поменяю путь - то все меняется, но тоже не всегда. А теперь самый прикол:
я удалил папочку assets ПОЛНОСТЬЮ, вырезал ее на другой диск. Но сайт, откуда-то, умурдяется его импортить, хотя по этому пути его нет. И да, я проверил все уже раз 20, иначе я бы сюда не писал. Кто-нибудь сталкивался? Уже бесит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очисти кеш браузера.

Answer (score 0):

100% не правильный путь с стилям css

Comment: Оно мне уже давно не надо, но путь был 100, даже 1000, даже 100000 процентов правильный. Я бы просто так не писал.. я менял пути, а в браузере почему-то все оставалось. Не суть.